# Multiple resource get in asp.net web api

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

Web api's developed in java technology supports getting, updating etc multiple resources in single web api call.
For reference:

https://apihandyman.io/api-design-tips-and-tricks-getting-creating-updating-or-deleting-multiple-resources-in-one-api-call/

Any one having idea, if asp.net web api 1 or 2 supports such feature?

Comment: Why don't you try the techniques described in the article on WebAPI?

Comment: you can take bulk of json as input which will bind to collection then you can iterate it and send response in form of json collection

Comment: That will be a manual process of sending bulk of individual resource , process those requests individually server side, each resouce will have it's own transaction, so that failure of one will not impact other request in that bulk, and response will have individual status i.e. 201, 400   500 etc.., wright?

Comment: @user3176053 yes you can do that with asp.net web API none of the techniques described are specific to a particular language or framework. The only notable thing that I saw was the collection of response codes under a 207. That sounds like a good idea and should be easy to implement.